# TestNG pass test parameter between different test class

Tags: testng

Is there a way to pass a dynamically generated data and pass them to different test classes/suites?

What I have is the following:
A username/password pair is created by TestUtil.signUpNewAccount(); and I would like to pass this account object to other test classes so that their test methods can use it.

- Test1Class.test1(){// use newUserAccount .... };
- Test1Class.test2(){// use newUserAccount .... };
- Test2Class.test1(){// use newUserAccount .... };
- Test2Class.test2(){// use newUserAccount .... };

Comment: Someone at work suggested to me that writing the data to a file and use the file as the shared data storage for all test cases.  I particularly do not feel that this is the best option though it does work for what I need.  I am hoping to find a better/proper way here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using TestNG's ITestContext.  For test classes that requires the shared dynamically generated data, I have an abstract class that initializes needed data with @BeforeClass

```
public abstract class GenericWebTest{
    protected UserAccount ua;
    @BeforeClass
    public void BeforeClass(ITestContext ctx){
        if(ctx.getAttribute("username") == null){
            UserAccount ua = UserUtil.newSignUp();
            ctx.setAttribute("username", ua.getUsername);
            ctx.setAttribute("password", ua.getPassword);
        }
        us = new UserAccount(ctx.getAttribute("username"), ctx.getAttribute("password"));
    }
}

public class MemberPageTest extends GenericWebTest {
    @Test
    public void test1(){
        MemberPage mp = new MemberPage();
        mp.login(ua); //login using the already created user account
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use `@Factory` Factory allows you to create different test instances with different parameters http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#factories

Comment: @mruna-gosar I have looked at factory but it does not seem to be able to share data that are created dynamically.  Though you can specify different values but you need to actually know/specify what those are values are before tests even start.  In my case, I need newly created user account whose username/password are only available after the test execution has passed the beforeClass method.  Perhaps I am not understanding factory correctly?