# Generic code for accessing common variable from different classes in Selenium using TestNG Java

Tags: java, testng

I have multiple classes A,B,C,D.
My project has different flows and data from all above classes flow into a new class E. I have a common variable "num" in the classes A,B,C,D. For each new flow , I must be able to obtain this variable "num" value in the next flow to class E. 
I am not allowed to extend E to either of A,B,C or D as I want to make it generic since I am using xml file to run it. All classes are under different .java files in my project.

```
public class A {
    num=111;
}
public class B {
    num=222;
}

public class C{
    num=333;
}

public class E{
    int new_var=num;
}
```

My xml file is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Default suite">
  <test verbose="2" name="Default test">
    <classes>
    <class name="com.asdf.A"/>
    <class name="com.asdf.others.E"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Default test -->
</suite> <!-- Default suite -->
```

Comment: How does the question relates to `Selenium`? Shouldn't it belong to `Java`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TestNG pass test parameter between different test class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943952/testng-pass-test-parameter-between-different-test-class)

Comment: @Grasshopper, Thank you for the quick reply. But, in the link mentioned, an instance of the class is created. As in my example, I cannot create instances of the classes A,B,C or D. For each new flow, my flow goes A to E or B to E. I want to generalize the code so that the variable in any of the classes A through D i.e "num", must be fetched in class E. I was hoping if i could globally save the variable as some cookie, adn may be fetch it later without creating objects.

Comment: Solved it using data driver framework and saving the results into excel file and later fetching it from there.